What is the simplest method to import Github issues into Azure DevOps as issues?
We want to move just our issues from Github to Azure DevOps and would like to know if there is a simple way to do this (i.e. a tool from Microsoft or a third party). For help with what could be considered simple to me, I am a former automation QA/ Product Manager, so I have some technical knowledge but am not a developer.
Did some googling around the best solution but could not find anything straightforward looking.

These is a GitHub Action that can sync GitHub issues to Azure Boards work items, see "GitHub Issues to Azure DevOps".
This action also is the recommended way in Azure DevOps official documentations:

Azure Boards and GitHub integration
Sync GitHub Issues to Azure DevOps Work Items

You can try to set up a GitHub Actions workflow in your GitHub repository to execute this action.


Thanks. I did browse these but they tend to be for synching issues with existing work items or creating a work item when a github issue created. I'm hoping to initially create all my existing github issues as DevOps work items, preferably without having to update each of them to trigger a sync. Maybe I missed it somewhere in the documentation.

@DanO, I did not find other ways. If the action does not work for you, you may need to try developing a script to call the GitHub REST API to get information of each issue, and then call the Azure DevOps REST API to create new issue work item associated with the GitHub issue.
